# Mysqli guarda los registros vacios desde Php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenas a todos..... Tengo un inconveniente en el cual mi formulario deberia enviar los registros a mi base de datos, pero lo que hace es guardarme registros completamente vacios, dejo mi codigo y espero alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias..

Este es mi formulario, aqui asigno los nombres que se enviaran a mi siguiente pagina

```
 <?php
include('conexion.php')
?>

 <body>

<form action="guarda_usuario.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<h1>CONTACTO</h1>

<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" name="nombre" id=""  <br>    
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu apellido" name="apellido" id=""> <br>
<input type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu email" name="email" id="" > <br>
<textarea placeholder="Escriba su comentario" name="comentario"></textarea> <br>
    <select style="width:200px" name="juego" > 
             <option value="0">Selección:</option>
             <?php

             $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM productos");

             while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

             echo '<option value="'.$valores[id].'">'.$valores[producto].'</option>'; } ?>
   </select> <br> <br>

<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="" id="boton">

</form>
</body>
```

Esta es mi pagina donde envió los registros a mi base de datos, tengo puesto que si las variables están vacías las iguale a "null" lo cual creo esta haciendo y no se por que...

```
 <?php 


include('conexion.php');
  ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
} else {
$nombre = "";
}


  if (isset($_POST['apellido'])) {
  $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
  } else {
  $apellido = "";
  }

 if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  } else {
  $email = "";
  }

   if (isset($_POST['producto'])) {
    $producto = $_POST['producto'];
    } else {
    $producto = "";
 }

    if (isset($_POST['comentario'])) {
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
   } else {
    $comentario = "";
 }

$query="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido, email, producto, comentaro) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$email','$producto', '$comentario' )";

$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

 ?>
```

Comment: intenta quitando " enctype="text/plain"" a ver si esta afectando la captura de campos de la vista

Comment: Eso haré y ya te digo si funciona

Comment: amigo si me pones un comentario te pongo la puntuacion a ti, efectivamente era lo que me mencionantes del text/plain, muchisimas gracias

Comment: listo amigo, ya lo coloque como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elimina el `enctype="text/plain"`, seguramente te esta influyendo en la captura de información de la vista.

[Leete este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628249/method-post-enctype-text-plain-are-not-compatible)

Comment: gracias amigo, me ayudaste demasiado

Comment: @FernandoEspinosa para eso estamos amigo! para ayudarnos!

Answer (score 0):

No tienes cerrada la etiqueta input llamada "nombre":

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" name="nombre" id=""  <br>
```

Debe ser así:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" name="nombre" id="">  <br>
```

Comment: la cerre y persiste la situacion

Comment: Mmm está interesante. Imprime en log o con echo el valor de cada variable que recibes en el php. Así verificamos que realmente no estén nulo o vacíos y nos comentas.

Comment: si comento la variable me dice que no esta defenida "undefinided index, por eso puse los if, me quitaban ese error

Comment: @FernandoEspinosa imprime con hecho el valor de las variables

Comment: si la intento imprimir me dice que no esta defenida la variable

Answer (score 0):

```
 <body> <form action="guarda_usuario.php" method="POST"enctype="text/plain">
<h1>CONTACTO</h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu nombre" name="nombre" id="">  <br>    
<input type="text" placeholder="Escribe tu apellido" name="apellido" id=""> <br>
<input type="email" placeholder="Escribe tu email" name="email" id="" > <br>

<textarea placeholder="Escriba su comentario" name="comentario"></textarea> <br>
  <select style="width:200px" name="juego" > 
    <option value="0">Selección:</option>
       <?php
       include 'conexion.php';

       $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM productos");
       while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 echo '
<option value="'.$valores["id"].'">'.$valores[producto].'</option>
'; } ?>
  </select> <br> <br>

<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" name="" id="boton">
</form>
</body>



//codigo php

<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$nombre =isset($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : null ;
$apellido =isset($_POST['apellido']) ? $_POST['apellido'] : null ;
$email =isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null ;
$producto = isset($_POST['producto']) ? $_POST['producto'] : null ;
$comentario = isset($_POST['comentario']) ? $_POST['comentario'] : null ;

$query="INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, apellido, email, producto, comentaro) VALUES ('".$nombre."','".$apellido."','".$email."','".$producto."', '".$comentario."' )";

$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
if ($resultado) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error ";
}
 ?>
```

no cerraste el punto y coma del include en el html, no soy un experto en mysqli pero hubiese usado en assoc en ves del array, en fin ahi te puse el comido como yo lo hubiese hecho, me gustaria revisar tu codigo de conexion, yo lo agregue en cada llamado a php no aparte, y lo que te dije de revisar tu codigo conexion es por esta linea.. $mysqli->query($query); yo hubiera realizado la variable de coneccion asi mysqli_query($conn, $query); en fin prueba el codigo que te di.. revisalo y espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

puedes validar si la variable viene con un valor realmente vacío a través de las funciones **is_null()** o **empty()**, se utilizan de la misma forma que estas usando el isset().

Te adjunto un link con información con respecto al tema.

[Is_Null(),Empty(),Isset()](http://www.anerbarrena.com/php-isset-empty-is_null-4878/)

Saludos, espero que te sirva.